# Sumar varias veces en una columna

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo sumar las cantidades totales por artículo?

Desde hace unos días he intentado sumar la cantidad total por artículo en sql server pero no logro dar con una consulta que me de el resultado que espero

Comment: Bienvenido Sistemas Retorno a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: ¿No has probado con `select articulo, sum(cantidad) from tutabla group by articulo`?

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que utilizar el `SUM()` del elemento a sumar junto con el `GROUP BY` con el que lo quieres agrupar

```
SELECT Articulo, SUM(Cantidad)
FROM TuTabla
GROUP BY Articulo
```